# Using sed to only replace one instance

Tags: sed

I have a text file: file.txt

```
hi
bye
test=VAR
test2=VAR_BYE
test3=VAR_HI
```

and want to replace VAR in "test=VAR" but NOT "test2=VAR_BYE" so it outputs

```
hi
bye
test=VARIABLE
test2=VAR_BYE
test3=VAR_HI
```

I have tried the following and it does not work. How do I use sed to do this?

```
var="VARIABLE"
var2="s/VAR/$var/g"
sed -e $var2 file.txt > file2.txt
```

and

```
sed -e "s/\<VAR\>/VARIABLE/g" file.txt > file2.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not trying to affect the first instance, just the one that match exactly VAR.

Comment: The version with word boundaries [works](https://ideone.com/x8BLoR).

Comment: What sed do you have? The second one should work indeed.

Comment: @Quasímodo I am on Mac OS

Comment: YuanL, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Mac OS is the key - Mac OS is based on FreeBSD. FreeBSD regular expression extensions are different from gnu regexp extensions.

Comment: Thank you @mathguy for explaining, I just researched it and didn't realize the hierarchal tree of Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "only replace **one** instance" - I am inclined to believe you want to replace the **word** `VAR` with the value stored in the `$var` variable, wherever `VAR` is a complete word. Right?

A quick Google search for "FreeBSD sed word boundary" helps us learn that in FreeBSD sed, the word boundary anchors are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. So, the following should work:

```
var="VARIABLE"
var2="s/[[:<:]]VAR[[:>:]]/$var/g"
sed "$var2" file.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A portable solution is to include the end-of-line in the pattern, given by `$`:

```
sed 's/VAR$/VARIABLE/' file.txt > file2.txt
```

A more restrictive alternative (i.e., it requires a more exact match to make the substitution) would be to match the exact line

```
sed 's/^test=VAR$/test=VARIABLE/' file.txt > file2.txt
```

The boundaries you used in `\<VAR\>` are an extension to regular expressions. They are not specified in basic regular expressions required for [sed by POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). You found out that your version of sed does not support them indeed.